# Заглавные буквы в названиях (Кольцо Всевластья)

Tags: прописная-строчная, ономастика, буквы

Почему "Кольцо Всевластья" пишется заглавными буквами, а, например, "Великая отечественная война" — нет? В чём разница?

Comment: Вы бы пояснили, откуда и что это за кольцо. Не все знают, да и не обязаны.

Comment: @shampar, Кольцо Всевластья — это из Толкина.

Comment: @Глеб Я к автору вопроса обращался. Не сочтите за грубость...

Comment: У англичан часто принято все такие необычные названия писать с большой буквы, так как это перевод, то сохраняется и регистр. То есть в английском есть разница между a/the ring и Ring. Грубо говоря: ring - это "кольцевое", a ring -  "что-то кольцевое", the ring  - "это кольцевое", Ring - кольцо, то есть собственно название предмета или явления, а не указание на свойство круглости. Ну а если бы это было название кольца в русской книжке, русского автора, это было бы "кольцо Всевластья".